# How to read nltk.text.Text files from nltk.book in Python?

Tags: python, nltk

i'm learning a lot about Natural Language Processing with nltk, can do a lot of things, but I'm not being able to find the way to read Texts from the package. I have tried things like this:

```
from nltk.book import *
text6 #Brings the title of the text
open(text6).read()
#or
nltk.book.text6.read()
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because it has no fileid. No one seems to have asked this question before, so I assume the answer should be easy. Do you know what's the way to read those texts or how to convert them into a string?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Nice catch! Ah, documentation gap =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets dig into the code =)

Firstly, the `nltk.book` code resides on https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/book.py

If we look carefully, the texts are loaded as an `nltk.Text` objects, e.g. for `text6` from https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/book.py#L36 :

```
text6 = Text(webtext.words('grail.txt'), name="Monty Python and the Holy Grail")
```

The `Text` object comes from https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/text.py#L286 , you can read more about how you can use it from http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html

The `webtext` is a corpus from `nltk.corpus` so to get to the raw text of `nltk.book.text6`, you could load the webtext directly, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import webtext
>>> webtext.raw('grail.txt')
```

The `fileids` comes only when you load a `PlaintextCorpusReader` object, not from the `Text` object (processed object):

```
>>> type(webtext)
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.PlaintextCorpusReader'>
>>> for filename in webtext.fileids():
...     print(filename)
... 
firefox.txt
grail.txt
overheard.txt
pirates.txt
singles.txt
wine.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clarified it !

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they already break it up into tokens for you.

```
from nltk.book import text6

text6.tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

#generate sorted tokens

```
print(sorted(set(text6))
```